# Remove spinners from numeric field in Grid

Tags: kendo-ui

I have noticed in the kendoNumericTextBox docs that there is a property named  **spinners** that enables or disables the spinners.

The question is how can i access and set this property to false on a numeric field on a grid.
At the current stage i declare my field as number.

I do not know if this http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing-custom.html can be any help in this scenario or there is an easier work around.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a `spinners` flag in the initialization of `kendoNumericTextBox`.

```
$("#numeric").kendoNumericTextBox({
    spinners : false
});
```

**EDIT**

For using it in `grid` you should define an [`editor`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#columnseditor-function) function in the column definition. Example:

```
{ field: "number", title: "Number", editor: editNumberWithoutSpinners }
```

And define `editNumberWithoutSpinners` as:

```
function editNumberWithoutSpinners(container, options) {
    $('<input data-text-field="' + options.field + '" ' +
            'data-value-field="' + options.field + '" ' +
            'data-bind="value:' + options.field + '" ' +
            'data-format="' + options.format + '"/>')
            .appendTo(container)
            .kendoNumericTextBox({
                spinners : false
            });
}
```

Comment: I have already mentioned that in my question that there is a flag named spinners.  My question is how to disable that in a kendo grid field that is numeric.

Comment: Sorry! See **EDIT** for spinners in a grid cell

Comment: We need to do it this way because when `kendoNumericTextBox` finishes  the initialization the element is already rendered so it is not possible changing it via `setOptions`.

Comment: OnaBai Even after spinner is false I am seeing spinner tooltips like 'increase value', 'decrease value'

Answer (score 4):

late to the game but I just fiddled around with CSS and this seems to do the trick:

1. hide the select area within numeric textbox

2. remove the right padding which was added to allow for the selectors

```
 .k-numerictextbox .k-select { display: none; }
 .k-numerictextbox .k-numeric-wrap { padding-right: 2px; }
```

obviously inspect your html to make sure those styles exist and make it more or less inclusive depending on your situation.